# Python no detecta librerías

Tags: python

Estaba usando Python cuando veo que faltan librerías que trae por defecto y asumí que la instalación no se realizó completamente, lo desinstale, le quite todas las librerías y ahora al instalarlo las librerías están en su carpeta pero cuando uso el comando pip list solo detecta la librería pip y setuptools que puedo hacer?

Comment: Al eliminar y volver a instalar lo que haces es eliminar todas las librerias y instalar las que viene por defecto. Para instalar las librerias que tu tenias personalizadas tendras que descargarlas he instalarlas otra vez.

Comment: ¿Al hacer import  os,re,math; te da error?

Comment: has hecho el import de la librería?